# Unable to apply the command "wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2" to set default version to 2

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

When trying to set the default version to 2 (I'm using windows 11) I got the error `0xffffffff` as follows:

> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2
>
> For information on
> key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2 Conversion
> in progress, this may take a few minutes.
>
> **Error: 0xffffffff**

I've tried many solutions given On GitHub and some other places so far, but it didn't make any difference and got the error: `0xffffffff` again.
I've used [This Tutorial](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=install+wsl2+windows+11&view=detail&mid=CE8E43DEF807F29EF076CE8E43DEF807F29EF076&FORM=VIRE&msclkid=c78ec3d9cfe611ecb538e3b3faaa959e) on Youtube to install `WSL2` and again got the same error!

And also when turning on my pc, after seconds, I will run into an error saying:

> **An unexpected error occurred**
>
> Failed to deploy distro docker-desktop to
> C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\distro: : **Error: 0xffffffff**
>
> Some WSL system related access rights are not set correctly. This
> sometimes happens after waking the computer or not being connected to
> your domain/active directory. Please try to reboot the computer. If
> not sufficient, WSL may need to be reinstalled fully. As a last
> resort, try to uninstall/reinstall Docker Desktop.

The error above is because of the `Docker` app, and all these issues I'm struggling with are due to that I wanted to use and run `Docker` on my windows!

Can anyone help?

Comment: Thanks for reposting over here.  That's some good additional info on the Docker message -- That might be the key.  Not sure just yet myself, but hopefully it will generate some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

There's an [open Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4929) on the error `0xffffffff`, but it's quite old (and supposedly was based on a Windows 10 Insider issue).

According to [a comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4929#issuecomment-593532267) by Craig Loewen of the Microsoft WSL team:

> The error 0xffffffff indicates that the virtual network could not be created.

A few things to try:

- First, from my own experience, there are issues creating the WSL network if either of the following directories is encrypted or compressed:

  - `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\<packagename>`
  - `%userprofile%\temp`

  The `<packagename>` will vary based on the distribution you installed in WSL.  Since you have Ubuntu (a Linux distribution, or "distro"), the package directory should start with something like `CanonicalGroupLimited` and also have `Ubuntu` somewhere in it.

  Make sure that encryption and compression are turned off for those directories -- In File Explorer, right click the directory, select *Properties*.  On the first (*General*) tab, select the *Advanced* button and deselect the *Encrypt* and *Compress* options, if they are selected.
- From [another comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4929#issuecomment-591552998) in the Github issue (and confirmed by someone else), adding `vmcompute.exe` (the WSL virtual machine platform) to the exclusions list in Defender solved it (include Exploit protection).  See [this blog post](https://www.surfacetablethelp.com/2018/10/fix-hyper-v-not-working-after-windows-10-v1809-upgraded.html) for details.
- Do you have Hyper-V installed on this system?  It's not technically required for WSL2, but it does share a lot of functionality with WSL2.  According to [other comments](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4929#issuecomment-598390236) in that thread, removing Hyper-V or the [Hyper-V network adapters](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4929#issuecomment-707885128) and reinstalling allowed it to work.

It's worth reading through that thread (and anything else you find regarding `0xffffffff` and WSL2) to see if any of the above or any other comments work for you.

Comment: I couldn't find out this part: "**Make sure that encryption and compression are turned off for those directories in the "Properties" in File Explorer.**". Could you please explain it some more?

Comment: @Hossein - Have you encrypted any files with EFS or used file compression? What’s confusing about that statement?

Comment: @Hossein You keep tagging Ramhound, perhaps missing the point that he's not the author of the answer - I am.  I edited the post earlier to make it clear how to check for compression -- Please see the new instructions for how to check that.  Also, Hyper-V pertains to both Windows 10 and 11, but you may not be using it.  That's why I asked if you had it installed.  If not, that won't be applicable to you.  I'll also edit to try to make it more clear what the `<distro>` should be, but it varies from system to system.

Comment: @Hossein - Your follow up questions indicate you have a some research to do, my responses, have been perfectly clear. Please stop pinging me. All the links provided apply to Windows 10 and Windows 11

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thanks, I've found the distro you explained, but now what to do? For example: Now I have a folder named `AppData`, Should I check the checkbox saying: **Compress contents to save disc space** (after right-clicking on AppData, selecting properties, then selecting Advanced)??

Comment: @Hossein I'm sorry I missed your reply :-/.  I just noticed it when the question got bumped today.  Did you ever resolve it?